# Ruby 2.2.3 on Windows -- how to make a file unreadable

Tags: ruby, windows, file

For a test, I need to set a file's permissions to unreadable.  How can I do this?

The docs for the File class don't give me any indication that it can be done.

EDIT: by unreadable, I mean that file.open must raise an access error.

Comment: Define "unreadable"?

Comment: File.open must raise an access error

Comment: Do you have an example file which does this? Do you know how that file is different from other files?

Comment: Do you need Ruby code to change the file permissions?  Or are you asking how to change the file permissions so that you can test that your Ruby code handles it appropriately?  Those are 2 entirely different things...